# Regular expression to insert the underscore in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<div id='x'>ThiIssss_SSSSMySites</div>
```

```
$('#x').text( $('#x').text().replace(/(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/, '_'))
```

The output expected is:

```
Thi_Issss_S_S_S_S_My_Sites
```

Basically first letter even if it is capital it should not be prepended with underscore. Rest all places wherever capital letter is found if it is not prepended with underscore then prepend,  I tried lot of ways. Can we achieve this with regular expressions? Or should we need function to do this?

Comment: Can I just clarify that what you want is all capitalised letters to be prepended with underscore except if the capital letter is the first character?  The expected output has prepended underscores for _ssss which is not Capitalised,  _y and _ites which again is not capitalised.

Comment: Try `.split(/(?!^)_*([A-Z])/).filter(Boolean).join("_")`

Comment: The input is `<div id='x'>ThiIssss_SSSSMySites</div>` or `ThiIssss_SSSSMySites`?

Comment: @Julio the input is   ThiIssss_SSSSMySites

Comment: I suggest you add more test cases, but my solution should be easy to adapt now.

Comment: @karen we have these field api names mapping not done at the integration side. So I want to do this mapping. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.replace(/([^_])(?=[A-Z\d])/g, "$1_")
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var ss = ["ThiIssss_SSSSMySites", "ThisIsM_M_ySites"];
for (var s of ss) {
   console.log(s, "=>", s.replace(/([^_])(?=[A-Z\d])/g, "$1_"));
  }
```

The pattern will match:

- `([^_])` - Group 1: any char but `_`
- `(?=[A-Z\d])` - that is followed with an uppercase letter or digit.

The replacement is `$1_`, the backreference to the value stored in Group 1 and a `_` char.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bhMfU3/1).

Comment: So we split the string into arrays of capital letters starting with(and avoiding the capital letter if it is before and after the capital letter and join them?

Comment: @user533 See my explanation above, it does exaclty what I wrote there. Could you please let me know what the expected result is for `_MyS_ite`?

Comment: _M_yS_ite, so if i want for numbers also  for example MyS112 so the ans would be M_y_S_1_1_2

Comment: @user533 You are adding more examples in comments, please collect them and post in the question. Also, I can't understand why `_MyS_ite` should result in `_M_yS_ite` (and not `_M_y_S_ite`) if `MyS112` should result in `M_y_S_1_1_2`.

Comment: My apologies...I was confused about the requirement as this is related to other party dealing with our code. Now they made the mapping clear....we only need to preappend the _ before the capital letter if _ is not there...

Comment: @user533 please, update the question with the real requirements

Comment: @user533 Should I keep the `\d` in the answer? Or do you have no need processing digits?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am assuming that part would be there,as I have not tested that part fully. however, it is just a thing remove \d or not. Let us keep this